# Polymer number property assignment changes value

Tags: properties, numbers, variable-assignment, polymer-1.0

I have a strange problem.

I implemented a Polymer element for my heating control and have a property for the actual temperature.

The value of the property is something like 23.5 (float value).

When I assign the transfered 'correct' value to the property, the value is changed. 
To show the problem I added a console output:

```
temperature: 23 - states[id].val: 23.2
temperature type: number states[id].val type: number
```

As you can see in the output the value is rounded during assignment. I don't use any observers or something which could modify the value.

Any ideas why the value is changed?

Here's the relevant part of my Polymer element:

```
<dom-module id="hm-thermostat">
  <link rel="import" type="css" href="./styles/materialdesignicons.css">
  <template>
    <style is="thermostatStyle">
      ..
    </style>
      ..
      <div class="data">
        <div class="flex-display act-vert-align">
          <div class="mdi mdi-thermometer mdi-24px margin-right"></div>
          <div class="text-width" hidden$="{{small}}">Aktuelle Temperatur:</div>
          <div class="actualTemp">{{temperature}}°C</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'hm-thermostat',
      properties: {
        ..
        temperature: {
          type: Number
        },
        ..
      },
      ..
      dataCallback: function (states) {
        for (var id in states) {
          if (id.indexOf(this.deviceid) >= 0) {
            switch (id) {
              ..
              case "hm-rpc.0." + this.deviceid + ".1.TEMPERATURE":
                this.temperature = states[id].val;
                console.log("temperature: " + this.temperature + " - states[id].val: " + states[id].val);
                console.log("temperature type: " + typeof this.temperature + " states[id].val type: " + typeof states[id].val);
                break;
              ..
            }
          } else {
            ..
          }
        }
      }

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```